# How to remove 'My Default Home Page' from side navigation Moodle2.2.9?

Tags: moodle

How can remove or change the menu item 'My Default Home Page' from moodle navigation (Site administration->Appearance).

I changed it from language customisation but it is not reflecting in menu. I also tried changing in `moodle/lang/en/my.php` but no change.

Does anyone know how to change that? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is admin related setting so you need to update in the following file **moodle/lang/en/admin.php**

Update the string **$string['mypage'] = 'Default My Moodle page';**

But its not good idea to directly change in the lang file else  you can use **Site administration > Language > Language customisation**